# What is happening in this Ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

Given the following example taken from [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :name, :title

  validates :name,  :presence => true
  validates :title, :presence => true,
                    :length => { :minimum => 5 }
end
```

I understand we're creating a class based on the `ActiveRecord::Base` class. On the next line, what is happening with `attr_accessible :content, :name, :title`? Are we declaring a variable, creating a method, or calling one? What are the expressions like `:some_variable`?  What are the colons for? Could someone explain in basic understanding what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`attr_accessible` is a method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible).

> [It] specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via mass-assignment.

Its argument is an array of symbols (the `:` business, e.g., `:content` is a symbol).

The method iterates over the list of properties-expressed-as-symbols and adds them to a list of properties it's okay to mass-assign.

Most Ruby books should have discussed [symbols](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm).

Comment: so when I type this `attr_accessible` in I am really calling a method and passing it `:symbols` and they are `:symbols` because they have a `:` in front of them?

Comment: Thank you very much!  http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm is VERY helpful.  NO, my book did not cover basic syntax as well as I would have liked it to.  I'll probably have to read through another book which is focused on these types of things.  I used: http://www.humblelittlerubybook.com/book/html/index.html

Comment: @JeremyIglehart The method is called when the class is loaded. Ruby class definitions are just executable code. `attr_accessible` is a class method. You're passing it symbols, and the tokens are symbols because of the leading `:`.

Comment: thank you!  Just talking about these things helps a lot.  I wish I had a Ruby/Rails programmer near by so I could just sit down and rattle off all my questions.  Alas, I don't - So StackOverFlow is substituting for this.  I really appreciate it.  I'll go read some more books which will help me understand the syntax better before posting more stupid questions here.  I REALLY appreciate the pointers.

Comment: @JeremyIglehart I'm not convinced they're stupid questions; there's a difference between "stupidity" and "ignorance". We're all ignorant when we start no matter what it is--I've been developing for thirty years and am thrashing with some new technologies we're using at work; that's just the way it is.

Comment: Well, thank you VERY much for your support - you've helped me push along!  If you ever need help with SASS/Compass/Susy let me know (I know, all technologies based on Ruby - hence my new urge to learn Ruby ;)

Answer (score 0):

`attr_accessible` is a method inherited from ActiveRecord::Base. It's a meta method which you pass symbols into (which should be named as the class's attributes). What it does is make them accessible, so in another area now `posts.content` is now available to other methods.

`validates` makes sure of certain attributes before allowing them to be saved into a database. If the condition evaluates to false, it throws an error. Again first you pass a symbol with the same name as the attribute (in this case `:name`) and then you pass in a hash of the condition to be checked (in this case `:presence => true')is fa

Comment: THANK you very much - I appreciate the clarity you bring to this topic.  The more talk I have on this the better it sinks in.

Comment: That's not what attr_accessible does; attr_accessible makes the properties mass-assignable.